# How to: URL Rewrite Dynamic PHP / MySQL URL for SEO

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Currently my site's URLs are:

```
http://www.domain.com/accreditation_training_view.php?id=1
```

I would like the URL to be the page's title from the database instead. In the table, the title of the page is simply the 'title' column.

The page title is: "DISC Accreditation"

I would like the URL to look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/disc_accreditation
```

Some pages have the '&' symbol in them. I would like them replaced with the word '*and*'. I would like any uppercase letters reduced to lowercase.

I am just not sure the best way to attack the htaccess and corresponding php code. I have seen other examples on this site, but nothing exactly like this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Scott

Comment: Have a search for the word slugify.  That is the process of turning a title into a friendly url.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way to do it regularly by `.htaccess` because you need to get the page title (which is in the *content* of your site, where .htaccess can't access).

Yet, if you are using any **CMS** or **framework** (Wordpress, Joomla!...), there may be url-rewriting included (or via plugins), have a check !

Comment: Max, I can easily change the way my site works. I can pass page titles rather than ID's if necessary. In that case, all that needs to be done is removal of the .php and removal of the page file name - then replace spaces with underscores and replace '&' symbols with the word 'and'.

Comment: i understand better. Then, you should follow the piece of advice given to you by Gazler. You can have a look here then : http://sourcecookbook.com/en/recipes/8/function-to-slugify-strings-in-php (or whatever STFW will give you)